# Pushing a collection to a subdocument by Index?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running the below code, in an attempt to create a subdocument under an existing subdocument. The basic structure is:

User -> (Many Comments) -> (Many Ratings).

The rating object is a basic javascript object, with the structure;

```
rating: {
    userId: "userId",
    rating: 4
}
```

So, for the comment at index [0], I'm attempting to push a new rating with the following;

```
db.getCollection('Users').update(
                {id: "user123", },
                {
                    $push: {
                        comments[0].ratings: rating
                    }
                })
```

The return from the mongo console (with rating just set to a test string of "test"), is;

```
Error: Line 5: Unexpected token [
```

I attempted to get around this by wrapping comma's around the comments[0];

```
db.getCollection('Insights').update(
                    {id: "b5e5bf69-071b-4af2-99b2-5165b47499cb", },
                    {
                        $push: {
                            "comments[0].ratings": "test"
                        }
                    })
```

This is actually returning with success;

```
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 2ms
```

However, the subdocument does not appear at all.

Could someone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: ypou should post your user collection schema, containing comments and ratings; will be easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to this; the array[index] format does not work with Mongo. Instead, use object notation. So, instead of;

```
$push: {"comments[0].ratings": "test"}
```

use;

```
$push: {"comments.0.ratings": "test"}
```